# How to to emit/fire event from hooks

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am quite new to React and having trouble to get the hang on how to trigger some actual events from a hook where a `useEffect` seems rather wrong (and leads to misbehaviour anyways).

Is there any best practice or is the use of a hook a bad idea anyways?

This is a very crude example of a file selector.
The main requirement would be that the `processFile` should trigger an one-time alert if the file is invalid.

```js
import { ChangeEvent, useEffect, useState } from 'react';

export const useUploader = () => {
  const [file, setFile] = useState<File | undefined>();
  const [isInvalid, setIsInvalid] = useState(false);

  const processFile = (inputfile: File) => {
    const fileTooBig = inputfile.size > 1 * 1024 * 1024;

    setFile(fileTooBig ? undefined : inputfile);

    setIsInvalid(fileTooBig);
    if (fileTooBig) {
      // trigger event?
    }
  };

  return { file, isInvalid, processFile };
};
```

```js
export const ImageUpload = () => {
  const { file, isInvalid, processFile } = useUploader();
  const { t } = useTranslation();

  // "Wrong appraoch" as it would also show the alert when
  // translation changes or a hot-reload happens during development
  useEffect(() => {
    if (isInvalid) {
      alert(t('Invalid file selected'));
    }
  }, [isInvalid, t]);

  const onChange = (e: ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
    if (e.currentTarget.files) {
      processFile(e.currentTarget.files[0]);
    }
  };

  return (
    <>
      <input type="file" onChange={onChange}></input>
      <span>Selected file: {file?.name}</span>
      <span>IsInvalid: {isInvalid ? 'Invalid' : 'All fine'}</span>
    </>
  );
};
```

Comment: Could describe what's going wrong? Moving it from the hook to the `processFile` function seems like it would do what you want, what's the issue exactly? The use of a hook for this is fine, it just depends if you always want to alert the user (in which case it should be part of `processFile`) or if it's conditional (in which case as a hook as good as each component that uses `useUploader` and determine what they want

Comment: @JoeLissner The quick answer: The alert also pops up when a hot-reload happens during development. (while the selection is invalid).
Also when I add something like a translation-function it should be added to the dependencies and therefore might trigger the alert on a language-change too.

Answer (score 0):

You simply use a single state to represent the invalid state as well.

```js
import { ChangeEvent, useEffect, useState } from 'react';

export const useUploader = () => {
  /**
   * one could use three states here
   * 
   * undefined means the empty state
   * null      means an error state
   * file      means success state
   */
  const [file, setFile] = useState<File | undefined>();

  const processFile = (inputfile: File) => {
    const fileTooBig = inputfile.size > 1 * 1024 * 1024;
    setFile(fileTooBig ? null : inputfile);
  };

  const isInvalid = file === null;

  return { file, isInvalid, processFile };
};

export const ImageUpload = () => {
  const { file, isInvalid, processFile } = useUploader();

  /**
   * this is just, okay.
   */
  useEffect(() => {
    if (isInvalid) {
      alert('Invalid file selected');
    }
  }, [isInvalid]);

  const onChange = (e: ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
    if (e.currentTarget.files) {
      processFile(e.currentTarget.files[0]);
    }
  };

  return (
    <>
      <input type="file" onChange={onChange}></input>
      <span>Selected file: {file?.name}</span>
      <span>IsInvalid: {isInvalid ? 'Invalid' : 'All fine'}</span>
    </>
  );
};
```

Comment: I changed the example a bit: What if I need a translation. It should be added to the dependencies and therefore would also show the alert when the translation changes (while the file is invalid).